# What are some alternatives to NavigationLink for a macOS app?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I want to go from one view to another with the click of a button. Like if I press Log In, it goes to the "Home" view.

I tried to use `NavigationLink`, but it needs a `NavigationView`, which I don't want to do because it messes with the format of the app on **macOS**. What is an alternative to `NavigationLink` to get from one view to another?

Comment: If else ,switch, tabview, sheet.

Comment: Checkout `NavigationStack`(iOS 16+), it lets you do navigation similar to iOS.